# Use a numbered list of arguments to prove the argument: ((p∨q→r∨s)∧¬s)⊢(r∨¬p)

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

This problem is from a Discrete Mathematics class, and I am having troubles proving 'r'.

I also am not sure if I proved ¬p correctly. Any advice will be appreciated as I am ripping my hair out trying to think what implications I can use.

Here is what I have so far:  ((p∨q→r∨s)∧¬s)⊢(r∨¬p)

```
1. (p∨q→r∨s)              Premise
2.  ¬s                    Premise
3. (¬(r∨s)→¬(p∨q)         Transposition(1)
4. (¬r∧¬s)→(¬p∧¬q)        De Morgans Thereom(3)
5. (¬s→¬p)                Simplification(4)
6. ¬p                     Modus Ponens(5,2)
```

I know I am probably making this harder than it really is, but I am knew to all these logical concepts and I am not entirely sure what I can imply.

Comment: $r \vee \neg p$ means $r$ or not-$p$, not $r$ and not-$p$; maybe this would help?

Comment: You also applied de Morgan incorrectly: $\neg (r \vee s)$ is equivalent to $\neg r \wedge \neg s$.

Comment: You cannot prove $r$ and $\neg p$ separately, but only their disjunction. That is, you can infer from the given premises that at least one of them is true, but you cannot tell which one. Step 3 is correct, apart from the extra left parenthesis, but steps 4 and 5 are incorrect. Step 6 is correct in itself, but it depends on previous errors, so it will not occur in a correct proof.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen My fault on the mistake in De Morgans, I had that written down but careless forgot to change the ors to ands.

Are my steps 4 and 5 correct now? If so will that make this a valid proof?

Comment: Your step 5. is incorrect. The [simplification rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) is completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

$1. (p \lor q) \rightarrow (r \lor s) \quad  premise$

$2. \neg s \quad premise$

$3. \neg (p \lor q) \lor (r \lor s) \quad Implication \ 1$

$4. (\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (r \lor s) \quad DeMorgan \ 3$

$5. (\neg p \lor r \lor s) \land (\neg q \lor r \lor s) \quad Distribution \ 4$

$6. \neg p \lor r \lor s \quad Simplification \ 5$

$7. \neg p \lor r \quad Disjunctive \ Syllogism \ 2,6$

$8. r \lor \neg p \quad Commutation \ 7$

Comment: I would have never seen the Distribution on step #5. Makes perfect sense now though. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot "simplify" by picking one of two conjuncts on one side of an implication sign, to say it implies the consequent.

Instead: For your third step, assume the negation of the conclusion: $$\lnot (r \lor \lnot p) \equiv \lnot r \land p$$

That can simplify, under this assumption, to

$\lnot r$
$p$

From $p$ we can derive $p \lor q$ (disjunction introduction).

Now, given premise (1), and $p \lor q$, by modus ponens, conclude:

$r\lor s$.

If $r$, that contradicts $\lnot r$ derived from the assumption.

If $s$, that contradicts $\lnot s$ as given in the second premise.

Hence $\lnot (r\lor s)$,

So the assumption was wrong, leading to the conclusion,

$\lnot(\lnot r \land p) \equiv r \lor \lnot p,$ as desired.

Comment: I prefer `~` instead of  $\lnot$.

Answer (score 1):

```
4. (¬r∧¬s)→(¬p∧¬q)        De Morgans Thereom(3)
5. (¬s→¬p)                Simplification(4)
```

Suppose step 4 was taken to mean "with sugar and flour you can make pies and waffles": $(S \land F) \to (P \land W)$.

It would be correct to conclude that "with sugar and flour you can make pies" : $(S \land F) \to P$.

It would be correct to conclude that "with sugar and flour you can make waffles": $(S \land F) \to W$.

It is not enough to conclude "with sugar you can make pancakes" : $S \to P$

The 4 general rules are:

$$\begin{array} {cc}
\text{This is} & \text{equivalent to this} \\
\hline
X \to (A \land B) & (X \to A) \land (X \to B) \\
\hline
X \to (A \lor B)  & (X \to A) \lor  (X \to B) \\
\hline
(A \land B) \to Y & (A \to Y) \lor  (B \to Y) \\
\hline
(A \lor B) \to Y & (A \to Y) \land (B \to Y) \\
\hline
\end{array}$$